# Hibernate, get datas from both tables in a join statement

Tags: hibernate, join, statements

I want to use below code and want to get data from both tables, but how? There aren't any association in my hibernate mapping files.

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT cat.* from cat inner join owner on cat.owner_id = owner.id where owner.name=:username");
query.addEntity(Cat.class);
query.setInteger("username",'Duke');
List = query.list();
```

Comment: Which data from which tables in what form do you need ???

Comment: can you explain what field your each table have? and what exactly you want? can't you use outter join?

Comment: First table in MySQL database is Authors(AuthorId,AUthorFirstname,AuthorLastname), second table is Items(ItemId, ItemTitle, ItemDetail, ItemAuthor). I want to list all the Items and show which item belong to which author. 
I can do what I said, very easily in MySQL, but when talking about Hibernate, I'm really confused.
Here is my sql:
SELECT Items.*, Authors.* FROM items INNER JOIN authors ON items.ItemAuthor = authors.AuthorID WHERE ItemGroupID = 2 AND ItemFrontpage > 0 AND ItemDisabled = 0 ORDER BY ItemID DESC